# Dual Boot windows 10 on my Ubntu desktop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

can anyone help me? I am currently an Ubuntu user on my Desktop, and I want to dual boot my Desktop, so I can have Ubuntu and Windows 10. Can anyone give me an instruction on how to do it? and i have a windows 10 bootable usb

Comment: Backup all your data. Make an Ubuntu install USB. Install Windows...which might erase your Ubuntu install and all data. We have no control over the Windows installer. Shrink your Windows partitions to make space for Ubuntu. Reinstall Ubuntu alongside Windows. Restore your back-up data. Personally, I think that's too much work and risk -- I simply run Windows in a Virtual Machine on my Ubuntu host.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/6321/889639) is the best description for install windows alongside with ubuntu.

be careful to make backup, because you probably should change file system to NTFS to install windows.

have fun